# Redirect wrong directory (status code is 200 NOT 404)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am having problem with redirects (or perhaps php include) for directories which do not exist.

Example:

- Correct path:

  olafernst.com/shooting.php = fine
- Typo in php:

`olafernst.com/xxshooting.php` = fine    (`404 redirect`)

- Typo in php and non existing directory:

`olafernst.com/xxshooting.php/nonexistfolder` = fine    (`404 redirect`)

- Correct path but nonexisting directory:

`olafernst.com/shooting.php/nonexistfolder` = returns:
status code `200` insted of `404` and cannot find the included php.

Any ideas?

Thanks

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html lang="en-EN">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Olaf Ernst Photography</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Olaf Ernst captures beautiful nature and stunning portraits with decades of experience. Visit to see for yourself. Landscapes, Portraits, Cities, Urban, Nudes.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="copyright" content="Olaf Ernst Photography">
        <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="8FC8C224898F3874EAA240BA4B1E6133" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

        <!-- plugins' css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins.css">

        <!-- google fonts -->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300%7cPoppins:400,300,500,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- main css file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <!-- modernizr -->
        <script src="js/lib/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>



    </head>

    <body>





    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you include? Could you please share your code?

Comment: Like this:  <?php include ("header.php"); ?>

Comment: I still don't see any code and don't understand how you achieve this: "olafernst.com/shooting.php/nonexistfolder"

Comment: Perhaps I want not describing the issue correctly. If you type this wrong URL into your browser the menu is not shown correctly. I would expect a 404 error for a nonexisting directory. I checked the return status and it was 200 instead of 404. All redirects work as expected. Only the ones with wrong directory name don't work. What code do you want me to share?

Comment: Do you use some .htaccess rules? How do you translate script name from the url to includes? Do you use $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] maybe?

Comment: How get that header.php (the exact value) into that include? Why you can't share your code?

Comment: I added to code above. Is this the one you are looking for? An no I do not user $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]

Comment: That's just a pure html, I don't see any part which is handling includes. Do you use any CMS or framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, checking your real live site, I think I understand the situation and can give you some advice and explanation.

When you enter a valid .php into the URL like shooting.php/nonexistfolder the part after the .php is considered as query strings (even if invalid) and the site loads up. You can't have subdirectories under a file (for e.g. the shooting.php). If you would like to use query parameters, they are formatted correctly like this:
shooting.php?key=value&anotherkey=secondvalue

If you would like to use friendly URLs like for example
shooting/amsterdam and shooting/rotterdam you need .htaccess files with rules rewriting URL-s and mod_rewrite enabled in apache.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You put me in the right direction. I think I can work it out from here. Thanks again. Much appreciated.